# How to replace full words that are either fully or part matched

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, str-replace

I am trying to use either **preg_replace** or **str_ireplace** to wrap a span class tag around the keyword found, however with str_ireplace it will cut a word such as 'wooding' in half eg:

```
<span class="highlight">wood</span>ing
```

Here's an example of needle, haystack and required return:

Needle:

```
wood
```

Haystack:

```
wood and stuff
this doesnt contain the keyword
Wooding is what we do
```

What I would like returned:

```
<span class="highlight">wood</span> and stuff
this doesnt contain the keyword
<span class="highlight">Wooding</span> is what we do
```

Here's a link to my preg_replace experimentation:
http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/i4m

Comment: Is your text already an html document?

Comment: No a PHP string (stripped of HTML)

Comment: Do you mean it doesn't already contain any html tag?

Comment: And how many keywords you need to replace?

Comment: Any that match the first part of the word. So the word to return highlighted could be woods, woodchurch, woodlands, etc

Comment: Ok, but I mean also how many different keywords: wood, banana, unicorn ...

Comment: It would just be one. This is for a search results page where search terms are highlighted

Comment: Hi Chris - that looks spot on thanks - please leave it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a regex and word boundaries with optional characters before the closing word boundary to make sure it is just the word you are looking for. Try:

```
$string = 'wood and stuff
this doesnt contain the keyword
Wooding is what we do';
echo preg_replace('/\b(wood[a-z]*)\b/i', '<span class="highlight">$1</span>', $string);
```

PHP Demo: https://eval.in/689239
Regex Demo: https://regex101.com/r/f9B6mL/1

For multiple terms you can use a non-capturing group and the `|` for term separation.

```
$string = 'wood and metal stuff
this doesnt contain the keyword
Wooding is what we do metals';
echo preg_replace('/\b((?:wood|metal)[a-z]*)\b/i', '<span class="highlight">$1</span>', $string);
```

Demo: https://eval.in/689256

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex: [`\b(wood.*?)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/u3wnhb/2), it matches a word beginning with `wood` followed by any number of word characters.

```
$intput = 'put your input here';
$result = preg_replace(/\b(wood.*?)\b/i, '<span class="highlight">\\1</span>', $input);
```

Comment: what if you have something before "wood" ? for ex "asdwoodasd" ? This is not going to work.

Comment: I am only looking to match text after the keyword so this might work for me

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
$str = <<<EOD
wood and stuff
this doesnt contain the keyword
Wooding is what we do
EOD;
$needle = 'wood';
$str = preg_replace("/\w*$needle\w*/is", '<span class="highlight">$0</span>', $str);
echo $str,"\n";
```

**Output:**

```
<span class="highlight">wood</span> and stuff
this doesnt contain the keyword
<span class="highlight">Wooding</span> is what we do
```